# Do annular rings have any influence on the solder barrel fill?

Tags: soldering

Does the annular ring size on PCB has any impact on the level of solder barrel filling for wave soldering? I've came across some articles about annular rings affecting the plating on the hole, just to prevent missed out from any other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

A bigger annular ring might improve heat transfer to the barrel so the solder may flow better into the barrel thus improving barrel fill, but I have no idea whether that would be of any relevance in practice.